# Radar next to HP

Tags: nether

Can someone explain the function of the lets call it "bar radar" on the bottom-right of the interface? 
It does seem to change when monsters are nearby, but I can not figure out how it works excatly, or what the hight of the sigle bars mean.

[image: See marked area]